# Are cyclic permutations always even?

Tags: permutations

I just discovered the permutation symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and was wondering if the set of cyclic permutations and even permutations are the same.

Comment: What does $\epsilon_{ijk}$ mean?

Comment: What about the cycle $(12)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the cycle $(1234)=(14)(13)(12)$ is odd.

More generally, cycles of even order are odd permutations and cycles of odd order are even permutations because $(12\cdots n)=(1n)\cdots(13)(12)$ is a product of $n-1$ transpositions.

Comment: An even simpler example is the cycle $(12)$, which is odd.

Comment: Oh I guess I meant for three dimensions.

Comment: You might want to add the formula: $\;\varepsilon(\gamma)=(-1)^{l(\gamma)-1}$,  if $\;l(\gamma)$ is is the length of a cycle $\gamma$.

Comment: @Malz Well all cycles of length $3$ are even, sure.